# Post json API response to PHP file

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json

I am trying to upload a picture to uploads.im which then sends back it's URL (and other info). The ajax post to the api is successful but I can't post the response to another file (saveImgURL.php) which would then get the URL from the sent 'data' variable and save it in the database.

HTML:

```
<form id="postfile" method="POST" action="http://uploads.im/api?upload" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <input type="file" name="file" />
  <input type="submit" value="SEND FILE">
</form>
<div id="result"></div>
```

Correct API response:

```
({"status_code":200,"status_txt":"OK","data":{"img_name":"abcde.png","img_url":"http:\/\/s1.uploads.im\/abcde.png","img_view":"http:\/\/uploads.im\/abcde.png","img_width":167,"img_height":288,"img_attr":"width=\"167\" height=\"288\"","img_size":"36.1 KB","img_bytes":37002,"thumb_url":"http:\/\/s1.uploads.im\/t\/abcde.png","thumb_width":100,"thumb_height":90,"source":"http:\/\/www.google.com\/images\/srpr\/nav_logo66.png","resized":"0"}});
```

jQuery:

```
$( "#postfile" ).submit(function( event ) {

    var data1;
    var formObj = $(this);
    var formURL = formObj.attr("action");
    var formData = new FormData(this);
    $.ajax({
        url: formURL,
        type: 'POST',
        data:  formData,
        mimeType:"multipart/form-data",
        contentType: false,
        cache: false,
        processData:false,
    success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR)
    {

        //document.write(data); // displays the correct API response in current doc
        $.post( "saveImgURL.php", { 'data': data } ); //DOES NOT WORK
    },
     error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) 
     {
     }          
    })
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: And how does `saveImgURL.php` expect to receive the data?

Answer (score 0):

The response you are getting is a JSON string.

Most likely you need to parse the returned data to a JSON object sometimes in the process, depending on how your PHP script (saveImgURL.php) will handle the data.

Either parse it before sending it:

```
var json = JSON.parse(data);
$.post( "saveImgURL.php", { 'data': json } );
```

or keep it as is but be aware you are sending a string, and parse it in the PHP script using:

`$json_data = json_decode($_POST['data'], true)`;

I am assuming, of course,  that 'saveImgURL.php' is in the same folder as your original file, otherwise the $.post will obviously fail.

Also - it seems as the string itself contains 3 invalid characters at the begining and end, which will cause you problems parsing it - the '(' and ')' and ';'; You can use a 3rd party website like [jsonvalidatoronline.org](http://jsoneditoronline.org/) to validate the response.

Hope this helps!